# MySQL/MariaDB Binding Address Server Public Address Or :: or 0.0.0.0?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

As a preamble, I have developed my own CRM (something like SalesForce or SAP) of a much much lower "scale" as it is oriented for services, not sales. I use MySql or MariaDB (preferred now) on Ubuntu 16.04 server to save all data.
I have always used the MySQL or MariaDB server **public IP address** as the binding address in my.cnf, and it all has worked fine for years. But sometimes it just stops allowing communication from the outside world (It allow connections locally), when it does it does not allow outside connections anymore until I change the binding IP to 0.0.0.0 or:: then it all works. So the question is, **what happens?** I am also a little concern about using 0.0.0.0 (ipv4) or:: (ipv6) for the binding address because I am not sure if there is any higher security risk when doing this.

I do run a Master to Master connection and the second Master do have the public address as the binding address and it is working fine.

The Ubuntu internal firewall is disabled as I rely on another firewall for it. I have disabled this firewall for a few seconds for testing but the problem persists. I do use Fail2Ban for Linux but nothing is being blocked.

What do you guys think might be causing the change in behavior (not allowing external connections)?
Is there any benefit of using the Public IP address as the binding address?
What are the risks of using 0.0.0.0 for the binding address instead of the server public address?

Is it better to use :: than 0.0.0.0? what are the benefits?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check your mysql database User and Db tables. You MUST have a proper GRANT for the external IP your a re trying to reach from. You will need something like

```
GRANT ALL ON <database>.* TO 'externaluser'@'external_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'whatever';
```

Otherwise, MySQL will not allow access

Comment: Jacques Amar, Thanks for the answer. I have been using the system with the same user for years, it suddenly stop. I have, of course, done your suggestion years ago the user@ServerPublicIP have all privileges. And yes I did re-checked the users and their permissions which are still intact. So the doubt remains, what is going on? and also is using 0.0.0.0 as binding address dangerous?

Comment: re-reading your original post, I'm confused. Are you behind a NAT firewall? Are the external IP and internal IPs are not the same?

Comment: Yes, in this case I am behind a NAT router.  This is a test server I have.

Comment: Need a internet Diagram of servers to understand: Machines (internal IP) Firewall (NAT type used i.e. one to one NAT or just PAT and how is 3306 handled by your firewall)/External IPs.  It's very weird to me that you attach to your EXTERNAL IP. Each machine should be binding to the INTERNAL IP and the firewalls/NAT should handle translations. Binding to the wrong IP will make it that only local connections work and binding to 0.0.0.0 means bind to ALL interfaces/IPs